# How to access twig object values?

Tags: theming, 8

I have an object called 'attributes' available to me in a twig template. Given that the following:

```
{{ dump(attributes) }}
{{ dump(attributes.storage) }}
{{ dump(attributes.storage['data-quickedit-field-id']) }}
```

dumps this:

[image]

how do I access the value property:?

```
'paragraph/3/field_section_title/en/default'
```

I've tried the obvious:

```
{{ dump(attributes.storage['data-quickedit-field-id'].value) }}
```

The following methods are available to me:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe it to `render`:

```
{{ attributes.storage['data-quickedit-field-id']|render }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetGet` and `render` :

```
{{ attributes.offsetGet('data-quickedit-field-id')|render  }}
```

Source : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Attribute.php/function/Attribute%3A%3AoffsetGet/8.2.x